# T-SQL Find when a amount has reached a set value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with data like:

```
ID  Amount  Status
1   15.00   Paid
2   3.00    Paid
3   10.00   Awaiting
4   12.00   Awaiting
```

The system looks at this table to see if a customer has paid enough for a subscription. This uses a table to record payments. Once a day I need to see if the customer has met this requirement.

The solution looks nothing like the above table as it much more complex, but the issue remain the same and can be broken down to this.

I need to find a way to add the amounts up, but when the amount goes over 20, change the data in the table as follows:

```
ID  Amount  Status
1   15.00   Paid
2   3.00    Paid
3   2.00    Paid               <= Customer has reached payment level
4   12.00   Cancelled          <= Subsequent payment is cancelled
5   8.00    BForward           <= Extra money is brought forward
```

Currently I am using a cursor, but performance is bad, as expected.

Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking or what it is that you have done that doesn't work.

Comment: please show some sample expected output based on your input

Comment: I think you are on the right track with a cursor. I don't see any better way.

Comment: If the solution looks nothing like the above table then it's almost impossible to answer this. We don't need every detail, but we need to be able to understand the structure.

Comment: with no sql code shown, no structure, only data (and not the real data or structure, actually), how do you expect help improving it? please post the code and the structure.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a running total to me. And as such a cursor is definitely not the best approach. Which version of sql server are you using? The technique will vary considerably. Also, you need to provide some details. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Generates the desired results.  Not sure why you would want to update the original data (assuming this is transnational data)

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Amount money,Status varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
(1,15.00,'Paid'),
(2,3.00,'Paid'),
(3,10.00,'Awaiting'),
(4,12.00,'Awaiting')

;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,SumTotal=sum(Amount) over (Order By ID) 
     From  @Table
), cteExtended as (
    Select *
          ,Forward   = IIF(SumTotal>20 and SumTotal-Amount<20,SumTotal-20,0)
          ,Cancelled = IIF(SumTotal>20 and SumTotal-Amount>20,Amount,0)
     From cteBase
)
Select ID,Amount,Status='Paid' from cteExtended Where Forward+Cancelled=0
Union All
Select ID,Amount=Amount-Forward,Status='Paid' from cteExtended Where Forward>0
Union All
Select ID,Amount,Status='Cancelled' from cteExtended Where Cancelled>0
Union All
Select ID=(Select Count(*) from cteBase)+Row_Number() over (Order by ID),Amount=Forward,Status='BForward' from cteExtended Where Forward>0
Order By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  Amount  Status
1   15.00   Paid
2   3.00    Paid
3   2.00    Paid
4   12.00   Cancelled
5   8.00    BForward
```

Comment: It does, but only for what I have typed. If I change Id 2 to Awaiting, It does not work.

Comment: change the first query after the cte to Select ID,Amount,Status='Paid' from cteExtended Where Forward+Cancelled=0